# Entity Framework : Wrong count with association

Tags: entity-framework, count

I have an object with a one-to-many relation with another entity which is eager loaded.

I use the paginatedList of the nerddinner example, as a result I do the count on the fully formed query (with all the associations and filters).

When I do the count, the total returned includes the association (lines are duplicated as many times as the number of objects in the child association).
I tried a do a distinct on the parent entitiy but it does not work.

What can I do?

Edit:

I use the Mysql connector to connect to the db, and here is my code:

```
public class Post
{
[Key]
[Column("idPost")]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }

[Column("title")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
public string Title { get; set; }

(....)


[InverseProperty("Post")]
public ICollection<PostCategory> Categories { get; set; }

}

public class PostCategory
{
[Key, Column("idPost", Order = 0)]
public int PostID { get; set; }

[Key, Column("name", Order = 1)]
public string Category { get; set; }

[Association("PostCategory_Post", "PostID", "ID")]
public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

//The call

```
postRepository.GetAll().Includes(p => p.Categories).Count();
```

with

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{

    IQueryable<T> query = dbContext.Set<T>();
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Can you show example of query where this happens?

Comment: Also please show your `GetAll` method.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried exactly your code with EF 4.3.1 and the `Count` behaves as expected - it counts only principal entities (`Post`). It even doesn't perform any join in the database:

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Btw. why are you using `Include` in query where you want just `Count`? It makes no sense.

Comment: I also use EF 4.3.1 and I can't manage to see the generated sql for the count (I am on a MySql db).
And it makes sense because I create my query before to paginate everything thanks to the PaginatedList of the NerdDinner example (see here : http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part8.htm#highlighter_938515)

Comment: Otherwise, is there a way to undo the include?

Comment: That is quite important information. You are using MySql so it can be some problem in MySql provider for entity framework because the behavior you are seeing is incorrect.

Comment: The workaround for you is using separate query for count without include.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to modify the query to remove all the includes but keep the filters? I'd hate to pass two queries to my paginatedList... thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can remove `Include` but it most probably means getting expression tree from the query and somehow modify it. I think it is too much complex. You can also try to use different provider for MySql if this also happens.

Comment: what do you mean by different provider for MySql?

Comment: What provider are you using at the moment? Connector/NET? If so try to use DevArt's provider or vice-versa.

Comment: Yes I'm using the official Mysql connector. I checked DevArt's one but it's quite expensive... Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue with EF6 with an include. If I materialize the query with a ToList or something it gets the right number of rows, but calling count on the query itself gets the rows * navigation properties instead of just the rows.

I have the include because I use the navigation properties later in the process and was trying to get everything in a single call. 

Its just very odd behavior that I would like to see an explanation for.